# Show area cover based on lineString

Tags: openlayers-3

What I am trying to do is display the area covered by someone.  For example a search team walks through a field, a person could see roughly 50m either way.  So I would want to display essentially a polygon with the width of 100m and the length of the path that has been walked.  I would need to both display this graphically and in an area measurement.

The best idea I have to implement this is to create a line string and then create a polygon from that by somehow setting the points 90 degrees from the line of point A to point B.  Something like this:

```
         |                 |
         |                 |
Point A  +-----------------+ Point B
         |                 |
         |                 |
```

However, I have no idea how I would get an angle from the line in order to find the coordinates to create the polygon.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution eventually.  Basically you need to use `ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle`.  If you set the number of points to 2 it will give you a horizontal line which you can rotate to the heading direction.

```
var theCircle = new ol.geom.Circle(theMarker.getCoordinates(), Radius);
var polyCircle = new ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(theCircle, 2, heading);
var polyCircleCoords = polyCircle.getCoordinates();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuDYJe?p=preview).

I use this function to generate the coordinates:

```
function rotate(xCoord, yCoord, angle, length) {
    length = typeof length !== 'undefined' ? length : 10;
    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180; // if you're using degrees instead of radians
    return [
        length * Math.cos(angle) + xCoord, 
        length * Math.sin(angle) + yCoord
    ];
}
```